# Why would Webpack 2 Ahead-Of-Time compilation not include the Map class?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

I've been converting a Webpack 1 application to version 2, mostly for the benefits of AOT compilation and tree-shaking.  At present, the code compiles - but when I test it, the application crashes out because the Map class and its constructor can't be found.  Since many modules make use of *x = new Map()* constructs, this is cramping my style.

Can anyone suggest why such a basic class wouldn't be included in the AOT build, please?

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a JavaScript built-in data structure, which has been added with ES6/ES2015. You're probably using a browser that doesn't support it (see [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility)). If you want to make it available for browsers that don't support it natively, you have to include a polyfill such as [Map](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#map) from [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js).

Comment: I'm using an up-to-date browser and core-js is already in my package.json file. Hence the mystery.